# Как передать тело функции в другую функцию?

Tags: c++, функции, классы, указатели

Например, есть функция в классе:

```
Class Foos
{
    public:
    void Foo(){
       
    }
}


void Foo2()
{
    int a = 2+2;
    std:cout << a;
}

int main()
{
    Foos foo;
    //foo.Foo() = Foo2; Как мне сюда передать тело функции? 
}
```

Comment: Что вы понимаете под "*передать тело функции*"?

Comment: @HarryfromKiev чтобы все содержимое функции **Foo2** скопировалось в **foo.Foo()**, но не объявлять саму функцию в функции

Comment: вероятно, вам нужен указатель на функцию: в классе `Foos` замените `void Foo(){}` на `void (*Foo)();`  А в `main` используйте: `foo.Foo = Foo2`

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Ну просто вызовите ее из `Foo` :)

Comment: @HarryfromKiev у меня будет их несколько, и надо каждом экземпляру задать свою функцию

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы этого хотите?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

class Foos
{
public:
    Foos(void (*f)()= nullptr): f(f){}
    void Foo()
    {
        if (f) f();
    }
private:
    void (*f)() = nullptr;
};

void Foo1()
{
    cout << "Foo1\n";
}

void Foo2()
{
    cout << "Foo2\n";
}

void Foo3()
{
    cout << "Foo3\n";
}

int main()
{
    Foos foo1(Foo1), foo2(Foo2), foo3(Foo3);

    foo1.Foo();
    foo2.Foo();
    foo3.Foo();
}
```

Comment: Да,спасибо. Кстати, а можно вообще сделать все так же, только прописывать алгоритм сразу в экземпляре?

Comment: И можете,пожалуйста, рассказать подробнее, как работает эта строчка **Foos(void (*f)()= nullptr): f(f){}**, что дает тут наследование?

Comment: Здесь нет никакого наследования. Поле `f` объекта класса инициализируется переданным в конструктор значением `f`, указателем на функцию... Вопрос из первого комментария не понял.

Comment: В плане, мы используем **Foos foo1(Foo1)**, а сделать сразу **Foos foo1(.....)** и тут алгоритм функции

Comment: Все равно не понял. Вы лямбда-функцию хотите?